# mongod getting Killed after successful running

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have my server on AWS in which I am running the MongoDB but all of the sudden mongod server get stop and showing message **Killed**. Then I restart the mongod server again but after 10 to 15 minutes mongod server gets stops automatically and showing the same message. This is happening again and again.

My AWS server is t2.small and I am running mongod on the separate screen on the Linux shell and node server on different screen.

The message it is showing is displayed in the image below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1gGo.png)

Please help me to make the mongod server running continuously .

Comment: hi @Ayoush can you show some client code
how you connect and use the db 
its seems like a failure in db connections management

Comment: i think you have to increase connection limit if you are using ubuntu , u have to set hard ulimit and run with fork

Comment: @NaorTedgi My code is working fine on other 2 servers but I am facing this issue in only one server.

Comment: @gauravsingh Can you guide me how to do that?

Comment: try this `https://underyx.me/2015/05/18/raising-the-maximum-number-of-file-descriptors` . and please show how you are running the mongo server

Answer (score 0):

You can run mongod in background as a daemon by using fork option and --logpath option.

mongod --fork --logpath /tmp/m.log

More info here

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/

Comment: It will make run mongod in background as a daemon but again it is getting Killed

Comment: Can you share which version of mongo you are running and the log files. If you specified /tmp/m.log then m.log will have your mongod logs, that will help in finding the problem. Please share your m.log file.